# Delocalization of eigenvectors of graph Laplacians

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, linear-algebra, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Let $(V,E)$ be an undirected, connected graph with $n$ nodes. The graph Laplacian is defined as $L = D - A$, where $D$ is the degree matrix and $A$ is the adjacency matrix. Let $0 = \lambda_1 < \lambda_2 \leq \cdots \lambda_{n-1}$. Let $u_2 \in S^{n-1}$ be a normalized eigenvector with unit length (if the second smallest eigenvector has multiplicity larger than one then we choose the vector with largest $L^1$ norm).

My question is: Is there a general control for the $L^1$ norm of $u_2$? In particular, are there conditions which guarantee $\lVert u_2\rVert_1 \geq \frac{c}{\sqrt n} $ or $\lVert u_2\rVert_1 \geq \frac{c\log n}{\sqrt n}$? For the other direction, are there examples such that $\lVert u_2\rVert_2 =\Theta(\lVert u_1 \rVert_1)$?

I searched the literature and found this is closely related to the `delocalization of eigenvectors', but many of those results are based on the random graph settings.

I am not  an expert on graph theory, so any help will be particularly appreciated!

Comment: Graphs that have a very sparse cut have the property that entries of $u_2$ specifies which side of the cut they are on (see Cheeger's inequality and its proof). In particular, the vertices on one side of the cut will have the $u_2$ entry be $1/\sqrt{n}$ and the other side will have $-1/\sqrt{n}$, i.e., they are very delocalized. That might be something to look into.